# Regular Expression generating strings

Tags: automata-theory

Can anybody tell me what strings can be generated from the regular expression (a+b)*   ? 
Can it generate abbbb and ababab. ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By "generate" do you mean "match" ?

Comment: Yes sir. It would be match. It was my mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Prrrrretty sure you could have tested this yourself faster than waiting for an answer here..

[image]

In short yes, the pattern you gave will find a match inside both those strings.

Note/ It doesn't match the whole input for the first one. It's technically still a match, though, so you have to be careful what you mean by "match"